# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.LinearLayout.getLeft()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

i got this error when i tried to implement Circular Reveal Effect.
Does anyone have an idea?

```
private void ChooseFile() {

    int cx = (mRevealView.getLeft() + mRevealView.getRight());
        int cy = (mRevealView.getTop() + mRevealView.getBottom())/2;
   // int cy = mRevealView.getTop();

    int radius = Math.max(mRevealView.getWidth(), mRevealView.getHeight());
```

Comment: A question here in Stack Overflow wouldn't be complete without some code.

Comment: A question here in Stack Overflow wouldn't be complete without a full logcat.

Comment: thanks you DaveNOTDavid and Rotwang :) i am newbie i'll make some good questions in the futur

Answer (score 0):

`mRevealView` does not exist. Make sure you set `mRevealView` to have a value

Comment: thank you for help, i already set mRevealView in activity_chat and call it in ChatActivity

Comment: the probleme is in  getLeft the parameters of animation reveal

Comment: You set `mRevealView` in another activity but in the current class it is not set. If you want to use the same instance, you need to pass it as a parameter to your current class/activity

Comment: thank you for your time bro :)  i resolved it  by puting compile ('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }                instead of :  compile ('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.0')